# Parsing line for string based on whitespace/tabs with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, parsing, whitespace

I'm using httpry to pull http packets from an interface on my machine. It outputs the results in a very clean format, with columns that are separated by either spaces or tabs. Here's a sample line from the output.

```
2012-11-27 20:29:22     192.168.1.132   74.125.224.51   >       GET     www.google.com  /       HTTP/1.1        -       -
```

I'm trying to write a script (in either bash or python) that grabs the website, in this case www.google.com, and writes them to a file. Writing them to a file is easy enough, but I don't have any experience parsing based on white space or tabs. If anyone could get me pointed in the right direction on how to do this, that'd be great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that `awk` is the tool for the job here (from within a bash script):

```
httpry -other -args -here | awk '{print $7}' > outfile.txt
```

Comment: This works great, however I did have to change the $6 to $7. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I counted the first 2 fields as 1 field :).

Answer (score 3):

In Python just use the split method for strings.

**code**

```
data = "2012-11-27 20:29:22     192.168.1.132   74.125.224.51   >       GET     www.google.com  /       HTTP/1.1        -       -"
print data.split()
```

**output**

```
['2012-11-27', '20:29:22', '192.168.1.132', '74.125.224.51', '>', 'GET', 'www.google.com', '/', 'HTTP/1.1', '-', '-']
```

Comment: This gives me a perfect way to start parsing it with Python, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LandonWO No worries, yeah python does a really great job at text parsing. If you want even more power check out [re.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) where you can split by a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "set --" in bash to split strings into words based on whitespace.  Example:

```
echo "2012-11-27 20:29:22     192.168.1.132   74.125.224.51   >       GET     www.google.com  /       HTTP/1.1        -       -" \
| while read line; do 
    set -- $line;
    N=$#;
    for ((i=0; i<N; i++)); do
        echo "Field $i = '$1'";
        shift;
    done;
  done
```

The output:

```
Field 0 = '2012-11-27'
Field 1 = '20:29:22'
Field 2 = '192.168.1.132'
Field 3 = '74.125.224.51'
Field 4 = '>'
Field 5 = 'GET'
Field 6 = 'www.google.com'
Field 7 = '/'
Field 8 = 'HTTP/1.1'
Field 9 = '-'
Field 10 = '-'
```

To extract only field 7, try

```
while read line; do set -- $line; echo "$7"; done
```